# during scroll event.preventdefault by class name (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to stop rendering during scrolling - add e.preventDefault().

please tell me how to do it right.

scroll I get automatically from the library and there is no props -onScroll

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYqjh.png)

```
   useEffect(() => {
  let scrollEvent = document.getElementsByClassName('ScrollbarLayout_faceVertical')[0];
  console.log(scrollEvent);
  scrollEvent.addEventListener('', function (event) {
    return event.preventDefault();
  });
}, []);
```

Comment: Please formulate the question decently, add all the relevant code, what are you scrolling, why is it re-rendering during scrolling ? That effect you pasted means nothing, apart you setup a useless eventlistener that listens to a non existant event.

Comment: I have a big table. rendering during scroll occurs because during scrolling, the mouse is on the table and a lot of functionality is written there,

Comment: I just want to disable all action when there is a scroll. so that the render will turn during the scroll

Comment: In react re-rendering occurs only when there is some state changing. So it means the table innerly makes some state change during scroll, and there's not way to change that from the outside.